# How can the submit button be always at below of the page even when new questions are added

Tags: javascript, jquery

When  is clicked the select tag is copied below but the save button remains in the same position. It should always be below the last question. Also the "Add" should only be below the last question

```js
$('.x').click(function() {
  $('.button-box').animate({
    'marginTop': "+=50px"
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".x").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer");
    target.clone(true, true).appendTo(target.parent());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="form-group" style="width:30%;    display: inline-block;">
    <label for="">SCHOOL</label>
    <span class="form-subtext">PARAGRAPH</span>
    <select class="select-box" id="cmbSchool" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Okul Seçiniz." style="margin-bottom: 200px;position: fixed"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" class="x" value="Add">
      <div class="inner">
        <i class="icon icon-plus"></i>
        <span class="text">Add</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button-box" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 right" style="margin: 0;">
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-midi" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/yusayalcin/vd0sz43m/6/

Comment: because `target.parent()` is the `div.form-group` element which is a sibling to the `div.button-box` where your submit resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you insert the cloned content after the button, as you append to the parent of `.groupcontainer`. To fix this change `appendTo()` to `insertAfter()` and target the last `.groupcontainer`.

> The "add" should only be below last question. Do you know any way to do that?

To do that you need to slightly re-order your logic to select the target, clone it with the 'add' button, then remove the button from the original element. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.x').click(function() {
    $('.button-box').animate({
      'marginTop': "+=50px"
    });
    
    var $target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer");
    var $new = $target.clone(true, true);
    $new.insertAfter('.groupcontainer:last');
    $target.find('.form-group:last').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="form-group" style="width:30%; display: inline-block;">
    <label for="">SCHOOL</label>
    <span class="form-subtext">PARAGRAPH</span>
    <select class="select-box" id="cmbSchool" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Okul Seçiniz." style="margin-bottom: 200px;position: fixed"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" class="x" value="Add">  
      <i class="icon icon-plus"></i>
      <span class="text">Add</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button-box" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 right" style="margin: 0;">
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-midi" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this one solved my problem. Also, I stated above that the "add" should only be below last question. Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer to show you how to do it

Comment: Thanks a lot these are really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can surround your code with a `container` like:

```
<containter>
<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="form-group" style="width:30%;    display: inline-block;">
    <label for="">SCHOOL</label>
    <span class="form-subtext">PARAGRAPH</span>
    <select class="select-box" id="cmbSchool" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Okul Seçiniz." style="margin-bottom: 200px;position: fixed"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" class="x" value="Add">
      <div class="inner">
        <i class="icon icon-plus"></i>
        <span class="text">Add</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</containter>
<div class="button-box" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 right" style="margin: 0;">
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-midi" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

That should work.

Comment: Glad I could help :)